# Blender reshaped mesh to voxel - want to keep weight paint and optimize triangles

Tags: modifiers, weight-painting

I have used the reshape to blocks modifier to turn a lowpoly model into a voxel model. The result it perfect.

But my initial lowpoly model was rigged and animated. The vertex groups and the rig look also good on the reshaped voxel model, but all weight painting has been lost.

Is there a way to keep the weight painting or do I have to weight paint on my own?

I tryed to "Transfer Mesh Data" and played with the options, but here the results of the transfered weight look bad.

I also tryed to assign the weight paint automaticaly (In pose mode assign automatic from bones), but this option is not available for some reason. I cant click on the button, its grey.

One last thing, Eventhough the reshaped result looks great, its not effcient. There could be a lot less triangles. Is there a way to optimize the mesh? Or is it just the way the reshaper works? I have to optimize it myself then?

**EDIT:**

On the right the lowpoly model rigged and animated, everything works, weight are also there.

On the left the reshaped voxel model. It is also rigged (its the same armature) Vertex Groups exist and are named the same, but the weight paint is lost.

[image]

Comment: that optimizing could be done with the decimate modifier but I wouldn't do it if you want to deform it afterwards with an armature.

Comment: Why would I want to deform something? Sorry I am learning right now

Comment: I thought you wanted to use an armature. Probably you should clarify what you want to make with a Picture in your Question

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: do you want the voxels to deform like your normal mesh would do or do you want them to generate and be aligned all the time

Comment: Tbh. I dont know. I looked up what deform means. If the voxel mesh animates then the voxels should deform, yes. I cant imagine how it could be possible without deform.

Comment: put the remesh modifier after your armature, dont apply it and play the animation.